# How can I automatically trigger all infowindows in Google maps once the page is load?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to display all info windows opened by **default** without user clicks the marker.

[image]

Here's my data array from google's site:

```
var locations = [
  ['中勝峰下山子寮 <br />100 kWh', 23.141162, 120.120495, 4],
  ['大江生醫S9 <br />120 kWh', 22.711022, 120.541029, 5],
  ['周啟正 <br />80 kWh', 23.317840, 120.267284, 3],
  ['禾豐 <br />200 kWh', 22.71637, 120.54331, 2],
  ['烏日高鐵 <br />110 kWh', 24.061611, 120.638747, 1]
];
```

Can I show these sites `locations[i][0]` by default without click?

```
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      draggable: true,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```

Please see my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytliuSVN/gm97dr5s/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code bellow. At the final of the answer post you have a code sample.

```
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-          FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var locations = [
            ['中勝峰下山子寮 <br />100 kWh', 23.141162, 120.120495, 4],
            ['大江生醫S9 <br />120 kWh', 22.711022, 120.541029, 5],
            ['周啟正 <br />80 kWh', 23.317840, 120.267284, 3],
            ['禾豐 <br />200 kWh', 22.71637, 120.54331, 2],
            ['烏日高鐵 <br />110 kWh', 24.061611, 120.638747, 1]
        ];

        function initialize() {

            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.890542, 151.274856),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
                myOptions);

            setMarkers(map, locations)

        }

        function setMarkers(map, locations) {

            var marker, i

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                var loan = locations[i][0]
                var lat = locations[i][1]
                var long = locations[i][2]
                var add = locations[i][3]

                latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, title: loan, position: latlngset
                });
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


                var content = locations[i][0];

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content, infowindow) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    };
                })(marker, content, infowindow));
                google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sample: https://codepen.io/calinvlasin/pen/zWqQaa

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked exactly how I wanted it, with a little modification.